# Selenium (with python) how to modify an element css style

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to change CSS style of an element (example: from `"visibility: hidden;"` to `"visibility: visible;"`) using selenium `.execute_script`. (any other method through selenium+python would be accepted gracefully).

my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.example.com")

elem = driver.find_element_by_id('copy_link')

elem.execute_script(  area of my problem )
```

what do i need to do in order to play with the CSS of the webpage ?

Answer (score 27):

Here is an example without using any jQuery.  It will hide Google's logo.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('lga').style.display = 'none';")
```

The same idea could be used to show a hidden element by setting `.style.display` to `"block"`, for example.

Comment: thanks, i have tried it only to receive the following error: WebDriverException: Message: u'document.getElementById(...) is null' ;

Comment: @user2627775, Can you confirm that the element actually exists and is not wrapped in an `<iframe>`?  Look at `driver.page_source` to see whether the element you wish to show or hide is actually present in the DOM.  Also, ensuring that you have the latest version of selenium might be worthwhile.

Comment: selenium web driver 2.33, and through driver.page_source i did confirm that the element is in the source. (id did:                    html_source = browser.page_source                                    if "whatever" in html_source: print 'in'. the problematic html is not in <iframe>, it's in a div/div/a/span. could 'bindpoint = "copy_link_wraper"' be the problem? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607582/what-does-the-html-bindpoint-attribute-do)

Comment: @user2627775, You'll have to edit your post with the website you are trying to scrape and the ID of the `div` so that we can actually run your code.  There is nothing else I can say without seeing the problem myself.

Answer (score 10):

Here is solution i found using document style sheets.
This way is great because you can also add pseudo class styling.

```
script = 'document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("button:focus {background-color: red !important;}", 0 )' 
driver.execute_script(script)
```

Answer (score 5):

String in `execute_script()` is JS code you want to run ([docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)).

If you use jQuery it can be just

```
driver.execute_script("$('#copy_link').css('visibility', 'visible');")
```

Comment: i have tried, got WebDriverException: Message: u'<![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \\"%s\\" but it is not present on the page.","#copy_link"]]]>' ; Stacktrace:. it appears that the element is only activated (or visible) on a 'hover mouse'...

Comment: what exactly is the copy link??