# How can i set new style of element using selenium web-driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am building test plan using (selenium webdriver - java) for page that contain button which open small color selection window.

this is the code of the right panel of the color selection window:

```
<span class="ui-colorpicker-bar-layer-pointer">  
<span class="ui-colorpicker-bar-pointer" style="top: 51.0333px;"></span>
```

the question is how can i set new style..... , i found this solution:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 js.executeScript("document.getElementById('colorPickIcon').setAttribute('style', '22.3333px')");
```

and it doesn't work....any advice's?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use findElement instead of getElementById,

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("colorPickIcon"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'top:22.3333px')", element);
```

You can refer the link [How to use JavaScript with Selenium WebDriver Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: thanks , i tried this and its still not working...
its Compiled but  the style doesn't change ...

Comment: For styles it is better to use like it shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911980/selenium-with-python-how-to-modify-an-element-css-style. This code couldn't work.