# I inspect element using Firefox IDE with css but when try access it using same at my code not work

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

HTML:
`<input name="txtAnswer" class="box1" id="txtAnswer" type="text" maxlength="20">`

Element can be selected using Firefox IDE:
`css=tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(1)`

I need to convert css that appear Firefox IDE to path can used in my code

`driver.findElement(By.name("txtAnswer")).sendKeys("green");`

Answer (score 0):

Try using **JavascriptExecutor**

```
JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("txtAnswer"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'colour:green')", element);
```

It's better to use findElement by unique id rather than by name.

More details here: [How can i set new style of element using selenium web-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882723/how-can-i-set-new-style-of-element-using-selenium-web-driver)

Comment: thanks for you replay also view same error "cannot locate an element using id=txtAnswer". i tried with may syntax but all view error. the scenario is login form have username and password , after i enter valid username and password and press on button login view page have security question this page that i can't inspect element at it. but it use selenium IDE it located the element

Comment: @AliSultan If you are referring by `id` attribute you need to specify that in your HTML like `<input id="txtAnswer" name="txtAnswer" class="box1" id="txtAnswer" type="text" maxlength="20">` and  `driver.findElement(By.id("txtAnswer"));` or for time being use `driver.findElement(By.name("txtAnswer"));`

Comment: this is my code but it not work:      
driver.findElement(By.id("txtAnswer")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("txtAnswer")).sendKeys("green");   maybe i need to wait after page open to access element.

Comment: @AliSultan wait for the element to be loaded in DOM. `WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("txtAnswer")));`

Comment: thanks but it view same error (Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: txtAnswer (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
 at Demo.TasheelIE.main(TasheelIE.java:39)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"txtAnswer"}

Comment: this is my code:           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();

  // Maximize the browser window
  driver.manage().window().maximize();

  // navigate to specified url
  driver.get("http://dxbqcapp01/molforms/login.aspx");

  driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).sendKeys("MS200963915");
  driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("test@123");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Submit']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
  driver.findElement(By.id("txtAnswer")).sendKeys("green");

Comment: @AliSultan did you try increasing the timeout.